# Regex - Capturing an optional string

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to capture a particular group of strings in a sentence like:

```
Agent/889 (SIP/1011 from SIP/1011) blablabla (Not in use) blablabla (last was 6 secs ago)

Agent/889 (SIP/1011 from SIP/1011) blablabla (Unavailable) blablabla
```

I getting all information that I want in this regex:

```
Agent\/(\d{3})\s\(SIP\/(\d{4}).*\).*(In use|Not in use|Unavailable)\).*
```

However, I want to get a #4 group, that capture, if exists, the content in "last was # secs ago". I've tried with regex like that:

```
Agent\/(\d{3})\s\(SIP\/(\d{4}).*\).*(In use|Not in use|Unavailble)\).*(last was \d{1,} secs ago)?
```

But the #4 group always get a blank value in array, even if the string contains the text in regex. I'm using preg_match_all function of PHP, simulating in this site: [PHP Live Regex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/).

Comment: btw you have a type in Unavailable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex

```
Agent\/(\d{3})\s\(SIP\/(\d{4}).*\).*(In use|Not in use|Unavailable)\)(?:\w*\s*)*(\(last was \d{1,} secs ago\))?
```

check the [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/YuBZ0e/3) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/YuBZ0e/2)

Comment: Very good! I made a little change to not capture in a new line when the string "last was" not exists: `Agent\/(\d{3})\s\(SIP\/(\d{4}).*\).*(In use|Not in use|Unavailable)\)(?:\w*[\r\t\f ]*)*(\(last was \d{1,} secs ago\))?`